# Is there a better way to manage a single subscription to a changing object's event in Reactive C#?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have a class `ClassWithProperty` that contains a property, `SomeProperty`, that is an instance of another class, `ClassWithEvent`, with an event, `SomeEvent`. The `ClassWithEvent` object will regularly change. I need `ClassWithProperty` to keep a single updated subscription to the event in `ClassWithEvent`.

I've come up with one way to do it so far:

```
public ClassWithProperty()
{
    IDisposable subscription = null;

    this
        .WhenAnyValue(x => x.SomeProperty)
        .Do(x => subscription?.Dispose())
        .Where(x => x != null)
        .Subscribe(x => subscription = 
            Observable.FromEventPattern(x, nameof(x.SomeEvent))
            .Subscribe(y => SomeMethod()));
}
```

This solution does work but it somehow does not feel like idiomatic Reactive code, and it also seems somewhat verbose for what I *think* should be a fairly typical problem to solve. Is there a better way to solve this sort of issue in Reactive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple with a `Switch` operator that switches to the latest produced inner observable of a `IObservable<IObservable<T>>`. It disposes of the previous subscriptions and only gives you values from the latest observable.

```
    IDisposable subscription =
        this
            .WhenAnyValue(x => x.SomeClass)
            .Select(x => Observable.FromEventPattern(x, nameof(x.SomeEvent)))
            .Switch()
            .Subscribe(x => SomeMethod());
```

If `SomeClass` can be `null` (which your original code suggests) then you can do this:

```
    IDisposable subscription =
        this
            .WhenAnyValue(x => x.SomeClass)
            .Select(x =>
                x == null
                    ? Observable.Never<EventPattern<object>>()
                    : Observable.FromEventPattern(x, nameof(x.SomeEvent)))
            .Switch()
            .Subscribe(x => SomeMethod());
```

Comment: WhenAnyObservable() is also another option which combines WhenAnyValue with the Switch(), but given you are generating FromEventPattern probably not usable in this case.

Comment: Excellent, switch seems like what I was looking for here. One aside here is that I've found information on Reactive in C# somewhat difficult to come by. Do you have any recommendations on books or other sources of info? So far I'm primarily relying on the 101 Rx Samples, http://introtorx.com/, and of course Stackoverflow .But in general  documentation seems surprisingly scant.

Comment: @RussellBearden - I think it is in part because the operators can be difficult to figure out how to combine. It's like getting 26 letters and hoping to understand how to write English poetry - there's lots of bad combinations that don't work. It's a lot of trial and error. My advice is to take one operator and try to see what it can do in something like LINQPad - then pick another one, etc.